# Set the Glyph Type to "Checkbox" in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm adding list items to a Google Doc. I know `GlyphType` lets you set the bullet type:

```js
var myArray = myObjects[i].myColumn.split(", ");
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     body.appendListItem(myArray[i])
         .setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
         .setLineSpacing(1.85)
         .setIndentStart(40);
}
body.appendListItem("Text").setIndentStart(40);
```

But how can I set the bullet type to "checkbox"? It is one of the available options within GDocs:
http://www.ultraimg.com/images/ScreenShot.png

*I suspect if I were editing an existing document with the glyph type already set, `.appendListItem()` wouldn't change the glyph type. But my project involves creating a GDoc from scratch and doesn't lend itself well to using a template (because the number of times the template text is used would need to be variable).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately It seems to be not possible... below is a small test I tried on a doc with "square bullets" :

[image]

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();    
  var element = body.getChild(1).asListItem(); 
  var attrs = element.getAttributes(); 
  for (var att in attrs) {
    Logger.log(att + " : " + attrs[att]);
  }
}
```

And the result : they show up as "normal" bullets.

[image]

Comment: btw, this is at the least an anomaly, maybe you could post an enhancement request on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)  (I didn't check if there was already something about it.) and thx for accepting :-)